# SNMP sanity check failed during installation of php 5.3.5 on Debian server

Tags: php, debian, php-5.3, debian-based

I am trying to install php 5.3.5 on my Debian server and after I performed

./configure -with-mysql=/usr -with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config -with-tidy=/usr -with-curl=/usr/bin -with-curlwrappers -with-openssl-dir=/usr -with-zlib-dir=/usr -enable-mbstring -with-xpm-dir=/usr -with-pdo-mysql=/usr -with-xsl=/usr -with-ldap -with-xmlrpc -with-iconv-dir=/usr -with-snmp=/usr -enable-exif -enable-calendar -with-bz2=/usr -with-mcrypt=/usr -with-gd -with-jpeg-dir=/usr -with-png-dir=/usr -with-zlib-dir=/usr -with-freetype-dir=/usr -enable-mbstring -enable-zip -with-pear -prefix=/usr/php -with-imap -with-kerberos -with-imap-ssl -with-imagick -with-readline -with-libedit

This error occured

checking whether to enable UCD SNMP hack... no
checking for snmp_parse_oid in -lnetsnmp... no
checking for init_snmp in -lnetsnmp... no
configure: error: SNMP sanity check failed. Please check config.log for more information.

Have you any idea how to fix that? (I have installed SNMP.)

Comment: really nothing? Come on! It really bothers me and still no answers.

Comment: as written in the error: Please check config.log for more information. But I guess 4 years later you have found the information:)

Answer (score 4):

You didn't say how you installed snmp, but I had the same error, and I ran

```
apt-get install libsnmp-dev
```

And it fixed that error for me.
(although I'm on ubuntu, not debian)

Answer (score 1):

For installing snmp on centos, use

```
yum install net-snmp-devel
```